# Java String find and replace a part

Tags: java, string, replace

I have an input string which looks something like this.

```
String str="abc + abcd * abcde"
```

I wish to replace

> abc with "xyz".

When I try replace function of string it replaces all the occurences of abc.

I should have the final string as

```
String str="xyz + abcd * abcde"
```

It is not necessary that  "abc" will be first word in String.

I need to replace only that word which contains `"abc"` and not the one which contains `"abcd"`. If I use `"replace",` it will replace all occurences of abc which is not required.

"abc" will have operator after `abc`. Something like this "abc+abcd+abcde"

Is there any elegant solution to this problem ?

Comment: Can you show your code? We cannot tell the problem without seeing your code

Comment: Try to generalize what the difference between the targeted ``abc`` is from the other occurrences...

Comment: you'll need to be more clear about your expectations. is it always the first "abc" you want to replace? is it every "abc" that is followed by a space? do you want to keep all instances of "abc" that are followed by another char?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati & DariaPydorenko it's not necessarily the first occurrence that is supposed to be replaced, so your linked questions are not duplicates.

Comment: @f1sh without further explanation of the OP, we can't say for sure whether it is or isn't the first.

Comment: @Stultuske OP writes ``It is not necessary that "abc" will be first word in String.`` which I understood as "the to-be-replaced string is not necessarily the first with the same pattern"

Comment: `str.replaceAll("\\b(abc)\\b", "xyz")`

Comment: @f1sh first word in String, and first occurence of "abc" in String is not the same.

Comment: This is not duplicate. I have already searched and found nothing was raised liked this. There are similar post however not what I am seeking. Edited my post to answer all the queries although last line of the post was very clear

Comment: So, "abcd" should not be replaced, but "abc ", "abc+" and "abc*" should be. What about a regexp like `abc[\s\+\*$]` or `abc[^a-z]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex word boundary matcher `\b` for this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\babc\\b", "xyz");
```

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html